# Is Śukla Yajurveda 26.2 also present in Kṛṣṇa Yajurveda?

Tags: identification-request, yajur-veda, shukla-yajurveda, krishna-yajurveda

Is [this verse](http://titus.uni-frankfurt.de/texte/etcs/ind/aind/ved/yvw/vs/vs.htm?vs026.htm) from Śukla Yajurveda also present in Kṛṣṇa Yajurveda?

> TITUS
>
> White Yajur-Veda: Vajasaneyi-Samhita (Madhyandina)
>
> Part No. 26
>
> Verse: 2
>   Sentence: a    yátʰemā́ṃ vā́caṃ kalyāṇī́m āvádāni jánebʰyaḥ | 
>   Sentence: b    brahmarājanyā̀bʰyām̐ śūdrā́ya cā́ryāya ca svā́ya cā́raṇāya | 
>   Sentence: c    priyó devā́nāṃ dákṣiṇāyai dātúr ihá bʰūyāsam ayáṃ me kā́maḥ sám r̥dʰyatām úpa mādó namatu ||

[Translation](http://vedah.com/product/essentials-of-yajur-veda/) by R L Kashyap:

> May I address the auspicious speech (Veda) to all the people, the people of the Word, kings, Shūdra, Ārya, one’s own kin, the complete stranger.

Comment: No, it's [found in](https://sa.wikisource.org/w/index.php?search=यथेमां+वाचं+कल्याणीम्+आवदानि+जनेभ्यः&title=विशेषः:अन्वेषणम्&fulltext=अन्विष्यताम्&ns0=1) Shulka Yajurveda only.

Comment: @Paṇḍyā You can write an answer saying you searched in entire Kṛṣṇa Yajurveda but it's not to be found.

Comment: Have you heard or read anywhere that this verse is present in both version of Yajurveda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, it's not present in Kṛṣṇa Yajurveda.**

I've searched in [Sanskrit Wikisource](https://sa.wikisource.org) which contains Saṃskṛta text of Taittiriya, Maitrāyaṅī and kāthaka saṃhitās of Kṛṣṇa Yajurveda but this verse is not found in it.